# How to use the same PCA on test as on training in Weka?

Tags: pca, weka

I have implemented PCA on training data and the result is ready.
Now I want to use the same PCA on test.
Is there any way to perform the same PCA on test as training in weka?

Comment: What do you mean "test" here? Cases that did not participate in the PCA and for which you need to compute PC scores?

Comment: the training data are which has class label and test do not. I have performed pca on training now, with the same parameter I wanna do it for test.
for example if the first attribute in training is "0.2*h1+0.7*h2" I wanna have this attribute for test.

Answer (score 2):

This is easily done by using [batch filtering](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Batch+filtering), that allows applying a filter to both a training and a test set in WEKA. Your only problem is that you will have to apply PCA to the training set again -- although you should get the same results if you make use of the same options.